# Accessing Class attribute from a called function?

Tags: python-3.x, class, attributes, inspect

Let say I have something like this :

```
  --module1

  def called():
     if caller.class.attrX == 1 : ...

  --module2
  class ABC:
     attrX = 1
     def method():
        called()
```

I want to access caller Class-attribute ?

I know I have to use inspect somehow but can figure how exactly.
python3

Comment: something like in module1, ```def called(caller):``` and in module2,  ```called(self)```?

Comment: yes but i want to be able to deduce the caller .. not pass it like parameter

Answer (score 0):

Passing a variable to the function is the best (and only?) option.

```
 --module1

  def called(attrX):
     if attrX == 1 : ...

  --module2
  class ABC:
     self.attrX = 1
     def method():
        called(self.attrX)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for object variable :
/if I can make it work for class-var it will be better/

```
import inspect

def say(*args, **kwargs) :

    obj = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals['self']
    if hasattr(obj,'aaa') : print('hasit')
    else : print("no")


class ABC:
    aaa = 2

    def test(self):
        say(123)
```

i.e. if I dont have 'aaa' set in advance :

```
In [8]: a.test()                                                                                                                                                             
no

In [9]: ABC.aaa = 2                                                                                                                                                           

In [10]: a.test()                                                                                                                                                            
no


In [12]: a.aaa = 3                                                                                                                                                            

In [13]: a.test()                                                                                                                                                            
hasit
```